# Send jQuery object to PHP through Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm **very aware** this is a possible duplicate, but none of the other questions/answers here on Stackoverflow solve my issue, and I've seen **dozens**!

**Here's what I'm trying to do:**
Send the object in jQuery to PHP through Ajax, if possible as an array (not mandatory, but preferable).

My **jQuery** code:

```
  var category = {
        id: $(this).data('id'),
        name: $(this).data('name'),
        brief_description: $(this).data('briefdesc'),
        description: $(this).data('desc')
    };

    $.ajax({url: '/ajax.php',
        data: {action: 'removeCategory', category_info: JSON.stringify(category)},
        type: 'post',
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
    error: function () {
       console.log("Error");  
    }, dataType: "json"
});
```

*The variable **category** is working fine, every index has its value*

Now my **ajax.php** code

```
$category = json_decode($_POST['category_info']);
//category['name'] should exist and have the value sent from ajax
echo "We did it?";
```

The problem is that the error function is called.

Comment: You forgot to mention what the problem is.

Comment: @jeroen it is not working, it's running the error function in the ajax call

Comment: use json_decode($_POST['category_info'],true);

Comment: If the error function is called, can you check in the browser console to see the request status ?

Comment: @RomiHalasz I'm sorry I don't know what the request status is or how to get it, on the console I'm getting:
"[Violation] 'requestIdleCallback' handler took 74ms" and "Error"

Comment: @xickoh Do a print_r($category); or var_dump($category); in your ajax.php code. What output do you get ?

Comment: You don't need to stringify while sending request.

Comment: @Bimal I'm not getting anything because the error function is being called, not the success one

Comment: @Harish removing the stringify and the «dataType: json» does solve my issue. How can I mark it as correct? :) Thanks a lot

Comment: Using `dataType: 'json'` tells jquery that it should expect json back. You send an unquoted string - `We did it?` - which is not valid json. You should use `json_encode()` on the output you send back (and only once to make sure it is valid...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You no need to stringify.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/ajax.php',
        data: {
              action: 'removeCategory', 
              category_info:category
        },
        type: 'post',
```

On PHP side you will get it in $_POST['category_info']. No any need to decode

Comment: I actually had tried this before, but the browser cache might have interfered with the javascript code and I wasn't successful. This works though, in fact, not only I do not need to stringify, but if I try to stringify it will cause an error. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
 json_decode($_POST['category_info'], true);
```

to decode it as array, otherwise it will be object

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that. It's not working yet though